# Scala file writing with Java printwriter - why does the file writer stop in this code?

Tags: java, scala, io

I'm working on a scala test case and using printwriter to populate some data.
This doesn't make any sense so me - it looks like the appender just stops 3/4 of the way.

You shouldn't need the code for the word count as you can see the last line in the file is incomplete:

```
hello world duck duck sauce sauce mazing ninjakeyboard skills ninja
hello world duck duck sauce
```

Log:

```
[info] Give a file with 10 words repeated on 1000 lines and file handler 
[info] - should give us an array of 10000 words *** FAILED ***
[info]   8434 did not equal 10000 (WordCountFileHandler.scala:20)
```

Code:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers
import WordCountFileHandler.WordCountFileHandler

class WordCountFileHandler extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers {

  "Give a file with 10 words repeated on 1000 lines and file handler" should "give us an array of 10000 words" in {
    val filename = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString
    val testFile = new PrintWriter( filename , "UTF-8")
    for (x <- 1 to 1000) yield {testFile.println("hello world duck duck sauce sauce mazing ninjakeyboard skills ninja")}
    testFile.close()


    val testOutput = WordCountFileHandler (filename)
    testOutput.size should equal(1)
    //testOutput.head.foreach(println(_))
    testOutput.head.size should equal (10000)
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you just add `testFile.close()`? I swear for a minute that was missing.

Comment: Ya I added it and it fixed the issue. Stupid bug. The scala io Source library doesn't need closing etc but java libraries obviously still do!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the buffer wasn't flushing - I had left out the file.close() and after adding it it works! 
Sorry to waste your time.

Thanks,